# Tagging AMI on AWS Regions

Tags: tags, terraform, amazon-ami, packer

I am trying to tag an AWS AMI that is given to me by another team. The AMI is showing under "Private Images". I cant seem to tag it with terraform even though the whole environment is built on terraform. Have you encountered issue like this? Any tool will help, I was also looking into packer however, packer does not seem to tag the image that it does not create.

I tried python script and bash script, but they are becoming difficult to manage when you have 6 tags. 
For example in python, I have to

```
Key = "environment"
Value = "dev"
```

So this becomes difficult. Any suggestion would be appreciated

Answer (score -1):

You can only tag  using Terraform while  resource creation or modification. you can  write Python  code  to do this. 
I can help you if needed.
please share the requirements in details with screenshot.